# Self-Relation in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I need to represent a League of Legends Item in my application (later I want to display them in the way as here:

http://lol.gameguyz.com/sites/default/files/Item%20Shop_Recommended%20Items_FollowUp%20(1).jpg

on the right,
i.e. as a tree structure). Note that every item might contain a list of items that are used to build it.

I've implemented the first version of the application and now I'm working on moving the data to a DB. I'd like to learn a bit about the Entity Framework. Using code first, I've declared my class:

```
public class Item
{
    public ItemID ID { get; set; }
    public int Cost { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public List<ItemID> Recipe { get; set; }


    public Item() { }

    public Item(ItemID id, int cost, string name,
                string path, List<ItemID> recipe)
    {
        ID = id;
        Cost = cost;
        Name = name;
        Path = path;
        Recipe = recipe;
    }
}
```

But in current shape it doesn't contain information about the Recipe at all (i.e. the resulting db  has only 4 columns - ID, Cost, Name and Path.
As this is a 0...n relation, in a traditional SQL database I'd need to create a new table with pairs SuperiorItem-ItemUsedToBuild. Is there a better way of doing so using EF ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while I managed to find a solution for my problem - here it is:

```
public class Item
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Cost { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Item> Recipe { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the context definition it's required to define a relation. As in LoL an item can be build of many other sub-items and can be used as an ingredient by many other items as well, this is a many-to-many relation. So the context will look like this:

```
class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Item>()
            .HasMany(item => item.Recipe)
            .WithMany();
    }
}
```

On the Database side there are two tables created - one to store information about items and the second one to keep the information about relations between items.